# How to flatten and split this JSON in Groovy?

Tags: json, groovy, nested, flatten

I could use some help with writing a Groovy script to flatten and split JSON into multiple JSON-s based on nested array elements. Here is the original JSON:

```
{
  "input_query": {
    "discount_guid": "3afeb169-7969-4f6f-8928-d801692848b1",
    "user_uid": 5467890,
    "shopping_list": [
      {
        "article_id": 311729,
        "current_price_without_promo": 7.69,
        "promo_discount": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "apply_discount": true
      },
      {
        "article_id": 229752,
        "current_price_without_promo": 11.29,
        "promo_discount": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "apply_discount": true
      },
      {
        "article_id": 193672,
        "current_price_without_promo": 79.99,
        "promo_discount": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "apply_discount": true
      },
      {
        "article_id": 261657,
        "current_price_without_promo": 16.99,
        "promo_discount": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "apply_discount": true
      },
      {
        "article_id": 318153,
        "current_price_without_promo": 13.99,
        "promo_discount": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "apply_discount": true
      }
    ],
    "discount_params_per_article": [
      {
        "article_id": 311729,
        "min_discount": 0,
        "max_discount": 4.12,
        "imposed_discount": null,
        "article_target_probability_increase": 1.15,
        "discount_downscale_factor": 1
      },
      {
        "article_id": 229752,
        "min_discount": 0,
        "max_discount": 7.52,
        "imposed_discount": null,
        "article_target_probability_increase": 1.15,
        "discount_downscale_factor": 1
      },
      {
        "article_id": 193672,
        "min_discount": 0,
        "max_discount": 60,
        "imposed_discount": null,
        "article_target_probability_increase": 1.15,
        "discount_downscale_factor": 1
      },
      {
        "article_id": 261657,
        "min_discount": 0,
        "max_discount": 12.4,
        "imposed_discount": null,
        "article_target_probability_increase": 1.15,
        "discount_downscale_factor": 1
      },
      {
        "article_id": 318153,
        "min_discount": 0,
        "max_discount": 8,
        "imposed_discount": null,
        "article_target_probability_increase": 1.15,
        "discount_downscale_factor": 1
      }
    ],
    "target_probability_increase": null,
    "request_time": "2019-12-21T21:32:13.018635"
  },
  "total_discount": 0.94,
  "article_discounts": [
    {
      "article_id": 311729,
      "discount": 0.04
    },
    {
      "article_id": 229752,
      "discount": 0.08
    },
    {
      "article_id": 193672,
      "discount": 0.61
    },
    {
      "article_id": 261657,
      "discount": 0.13
    },
    {
      "article_id": 318153,
      "discount": 0.08
    }
  ]
}
```

What I would like to do is flatten the original JSON to an array of JSON-s like this:

```
[{
  "discount_guid": "3afeb169-7969-4f6f-8928-d801692848b1",
  "user_uid": 5467890,
  "article_id": 318153,
  "current_price_without_promo": 13.99,
  "promo_discount": 0,
  "count": 1,
  "apply_discount": true,
  "min_discount": 0,
  "max_discount": 8,
  "imposed_discount": null,
  "article_target_probability_increase": 1.15,
  "discount_downscale_factor": 1,
  "target_probability_increase": null,
  "request_time": "2019-12-21T21:32:13.018635",
  "total_discount": 0.94,
  "discount": 0.08
},
{
  "discount_guid": ...
},
...
]
```

I've managed to get a single flatten JSON this way:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput as jo

def content = new File('response.json')
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def object = slurper.parseText(content)

def flattenMap(Map map) {
    def result = [:]

    map.each { k, v ->
        if (v instanceof Map) {
            result << flattenMap(v)
        } else if (v instanceof Collection && v.every {it instanceof Map}) {
            v.each {
                result << flattenMap(it)
            }
        } else {
            result[k] = v
        }
    }
    result
}

println(jo.prettyPrint(jo.toJson(flattenMap(object))))
```

But I don't have a clue how to get a full array of JSON-s. I am sure that there is an easy way to accomplish this, but I'm quite new to Groovy and so far I didn't find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `flatten` is not your primary goal. seems your primary goal is to iterate through articles and collect required information form parent object and other siblings grouping data by article_id.

Comment: I assume the triggere here is to combine all maps, that contain an `artile_id` and the maps that lead to them? Unless you expect some wild differences in the data you get and all that data will hold to that approach you might be better off to just pull out the data on paths you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of solving this would be something like this:

```
import groovy.json.*

def str = '''
{
  "input_query": {
    "discount_guid": "3afeb169-7969-4f6f-8928-d801692848b1",
    "user_uid": 5467890,
    "shopping_list": [
      {
        "article_id": 311729,
        "current_price_without_promo": 7.69,
        "promo_discount": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "apply_discount": true
      },
      {
        "article_id": 229752,
        "current_price_without_promo": 11.29,
        "promo_discount": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "apply_discount": true
      },
      {
        "article_id": 193672,
        "current_price_without_promo": 79.99,
        "promo_discount": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "apply_discount": true
      },
      {
        "article_id": 261657,
        "current_price_without_promo": 16.99,
        "promo_discount": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "apply_discount": true
      },
      {
        "article_id": 318153,
        "current_price_without_promo": 13.99,
        "promo_discount": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "apply_discount": true
      }
    ],
    "discount_params_per_article": [
      {
        "article_id": 311729,
        "min_discount": 0,
        "max_discount": 4.12,
        "imposed_discount": null,
        "article_target_probability_increase": 1.15,
        "discount_downscale_factor": 1
      },
      {
        "article_id": 229752,
        "min_discount": 0,
        "max_discount": 7.52,
        "imposed_discount": null,
        "article_target_probability_increase": 1.15,
        "discount_downscale_factor": 1
      },
      {
        "article_id": 193672,
        "min_discount": 0,
        "max_discount": 60,
        "imposed_discount": null,
        "article_target_probability_increase": 1.15,
        "discount_downscale_factor": 1
      },
      {
        "article_id": 261657,
        "min_discount": 0,
        "max_discount": 12.4,
        "imposed_discount": null,
        "article_target_probability_increase": 1.15,
        "discount_downscale_factor": 1
      },
      {
        "article_id": 318153,
        "min_discount": 0,
        "max_discount": 8,
        "imposed_discount": null,
        "article_target_probability_increase": 1.15,
        "discount_downscale_factor": 1
      }
    ],
    "target_probability_increase": null,
    "request_time": "2019-12-21T21:32:13.018635"
  },
  "total_discount": 0.94,
  "article_discounts": [
    {
      "article_id": 311729,
      "discount": 0.04
    },
    {
      "article_id": 229752,
      "discount": 0.08
    },
    {
      "article_id": 193672,
      "discount": 0.61
    },
    {
      "article_id": 261657,
      "discount": 0.13
    },
    {
      "article_id": 318153,
      "discount": 0.08
    }
  ]
}
'''

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(str) 

// a predicate to check if a value is a plain value vs map or list
def isPlain     = { v -> !(v instanceof Map) && !(v instanceof List) }

// for the two maps json.input_query and the root level json map, 
// find all plain values
def plainValues = json.input_query.findAll { k, v -> isPlain(v) } +
                  json.findAll { k, v -> isPlain(v) } 

// find the three lists of maps, group by article_id and add the 
// values for each article id to a cumulative map and finally 
// add the plain values collected above to each cumulative map
def result = (json.input_query.shopping_list +
              json.input_query.discount_params_per_article +
              json.article_discounts).groupBy { 
                it.article_id 
              }.values().collect { listOfMaps -> 
                listOfMaps.sum() + plainValues
              }

// print result
result.each { m -> 
  println "-----"
  m.sort().each { k, v -> 
    println "${k.padLeft(35)} -> $v"
  }
}
```

Executing the above produces:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
-----
                     apply_discount -> true
                         article_id -> 311729
article_target_probability_increase -> 1.15
                              count -> 1
        current_price_without_promo -> 7.69
                           discount -> 0.04
          discount_downscale_factor -> 1
                      discount_guid -> 3afeb169-7969-4f6f-8928-d801692848b1
                   imposed_discount -> null
                       max_discount -> 4.12
                       min_discount -> 0
                     promo_discount -> 0
                       request_time -> 2019-12-21T21:32:13.018635
        target_probability_increase -> null
                     total_discount -> 0.94
                           user_uid -> 5467890
-----
                     apply_discount -> true
                         article_id -> 229752
article_target_probability_increase -> 1.15
                              count -> 1
        current_price_without_promo -> 11.29
                           discount -> 0.08
          discount_downscale_factor -> 1
                      discount_guid -> 3afeb169-7969-4f6f-8928-d801692848b1
                   imposed_discount -> null
                       max_discount -> 7.52
                       min_discount -> 0
                     promo_discount -> 0
                       request_time -> 2019-12-21T21:32:13.018635
        target_probability_increase -> null
                     total_discount -> 0.94
                           user_uid -> 5467890
-----
...
```

the printout at the end sorts by keys and does some indentation for readability.

You can then get the output json using something like this:

```
def outputJson = JsonOutput.toJson(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is precisely what I needed.

Comment: If this solves your problem,it can be good to mark it as the accepted answer so others do not need to spend time re-solving your problem.